# Estimating norms of derivatives

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $(M,g)$ be a closed, compact Riemannian manifold. Let $u$ be a smooth function. Let $H^{-k}(M)$,, $k$ is a positive integer, be the dual Hilbert space of $H^{k}(M)$. Does it follow that $|| |\nabla^l u| ||^{-k}$, where $||\circ||^{-k}$ is the norm on $H^{-k}(M)$ and $l \in \Bbb{Z}_+$, can be bounded by $|| u ||^{l-k}$, where $||\circ||^{l-k}$ is the norm on $H^{l-k}(M)$?

Comment: I haven't tried to write the details down, but it appears to me that you should be able to prove this using just the definition of the norm on $H^k$, the definition of a dual (operator) norm, and maybe integration by parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  $P$ is a  degree $ l $  differential operator, then

$$ \Vert Pu \Vert_s <  C \Vert u \Vert_{s+l} ,\;\; \forall u, s. $$

Now take $s=-k$,  $P=\nabla^l$.